# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'jsonschema.compat'

Tags: python, python-bybit

I have been working with the Bybit API for the last week when I encountered the title problem yesterday. I have started a new env and installed only the bybit wrapper again and the issue still arises. From what I can see I have jsonschema installed and in my env PATH. It was working a few days ago, so I do believe this to be separate from whatever API I am trying to use. Included is a picture of the response when run in an interpreter. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'jsonschema.compat' is the error that comes up.

[image]

Answer (score 26, accepted):

That module was removed in `jsonschema` 4.0. Your packages haven't been pinned to only use jsonschema 3.x, so that might happen.

For now, you can downgrade to version 3.x of the `jsonschema` package with

```
pip install -U 'jsonschema<4.0'
```

and things should work.

Comment: On my Windows machine I had to use python -m pip install "jsonschema<4.0"

Answer (score 2):

I have exactly the same problem! It was working before the release of 1.3, with the version 1.21 months a go.
I found this problem to day after updateing my venv to the newest versions.
Search a little more, it is a problem with the version of the jsonschema-4.0.1, go back to version 3.1.1 of jsonschema and all is running like befor, incl. the version 1.3 of bybit.
Regards,

Answer (score 1):

For those who use conda

```
conda update "jsonschema<4.0"
```

or mamba

```
mamba update "jsonschema<4.0"
```

install instead of update will just say that already installed.

Fixes

```
from jsonschema.protocols import Validator
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'jsonschema.protocols'
```

as well.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue too, but in my case the library which has the requirement of `jsonschema` was `bitmex`. I downgraded the package on my `requirement.txt` constraining the version:

```
jsonschema<4.0
```